# Mac OS X resizing of windows when changing display resolution

Tags: macos

I use my MacBook most of the time with a high-resolution desktop monitor plugged in and the laptop lid closed. If shut down an application (in this case iTunes) with the display in this configuration and then open it later with the laptop's much smaller screen as the only monitor it causes a problem: Mac OS X resizes the application's window to the full resolution of the MacBook's display (1280x800), but because of the menu bar, it positions it lower down so the bottom of the window is off-screen. Unfortunately that's the only bit of the window you can use to resize it on a Mac. And to add further pain, in iTunes 'zoom'ing the window doesn't help because in the zoomed state, iTunes goes into mini-mode.

So, is there any way, other than dragging the bottom-right corner with the mouse, to resize a window in Mac OS X?

Comment: windows resizing is indeed a pain with Mac OS... although having two monitors actually make it easier to maximize them I find.

Comment: Related question here on Super User that should help: http://superuser.com/questions/331/reset-mac-os-x-windows-position-after-de-attaching-external-monitor (Question 331)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Holding down option and then clicking the green button in iTunes will do a "normal" resize like you are used to in pretty much all other apps instead of switching to the mini player.